# change color of a circle if the user position is within its range

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map on which there are some circles, each one with a certain radius, and on the page load, I get the position of the user and show it on the map. 
At first all the circles are red, so I want to check if the current position of the user happens to be in any of there circles, that particular circle should get green instead of red.
what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Google Maps API, you may use the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) to calculate distance between circle's center and the lat/lng representing the position of your user. Then compare it with your radius.

You can do something like this :

```
var pointIsInsideCircle = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(circle.getCenter(), point) <= circle.getRadius();
```

Then change the color of your circle if `pointIsInsideCircle` is `true`

Comment: awesome, just changed `getCenter()` to `circle.center` and replaced `getRadius()` with `Math.sqrt(circle.population) * 100` and everything works fiiiine.